# data-turbolinks false not working on normal anchor tag

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-5

turbolinks false not working on a button.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="col-12 float-left text-center mt-4 mb-2" data-turbolinks="false">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-primary primary-g mt-2 submit-form" data-loader="true">
      <span><%= I18n.t("app.continue") %></span>
    </a>
  </div>
```

I have also tried placing turbolinks="false" inside the anchor tag and it still does not work.